# How to implement `zipTree` using `foldTree`?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

How do you implement `zipTree`, which behaves like this

1. takes a `merger`, `tree1`, `tree2`
2. for each pair of node

   - if both possess value, merge with `merger`
   - otherwise turn into a `Leaf`

```
>>> :t zipTree
zipTree :: (a -> a -> b) -> Tree a -> Tree a -> Tree b
>>> zipTree (+) (Branch 1 Leaf (Branch 2 Leaf Leaf)) (Branch 3 Leaf Leaf)
(Branch 4 Leaf Leaf)
```

Using `foldTree` defined below

```
data Tree a = Leaf | Branch a (Tree a) (Tree a) deriving (Show, Eq)

foldTree :: b -> (a -> b -> b -> b) -> Tree a -> b
foldTree e _ Leaf     = e
foldTree e n (Branch a n1 n2) = n a (foldTree e n n1) (foldTree e n n2)

mapTree :: (a -> b) -> Tree a -> Tree b
mapTree f = foldTree Leaf (\x t1 t2 -> Branch (f x) t1 t2)
```

I only managed to implement the self-recusive version w/o using `foldTree`

```
zipTree :: (a -> a -> b) -> Tree a -> Tree a -> Tree b
zipTree f Leaf _ = Leaf
zipTree f _ Leaf = Leaf
zipTree f (Branch aroot a1 a2) (Branch broot b1 b2) = Branch (f aroot broot) (zipTree f a1 b1) (zipTree f a2 b2)
```

I have worked on the direction to return a callback with `foldTree` on `tree1` to operate on `tree2`, but to no avail

Anyone knows how to use `foldTree` to implement the `zipTree`? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you know how you'd do this for simpler data structures? For example, can you implement `zipWith` in terms of `foldr`?

Answer (score 8):

Starting with your definition:

```
zipTree :: (a -> a -> b) -> Tree a -> Tree a -> Tree b
zipTree f Leaf _ = Leaf
zipTree f _ Leaf = Leaf
zipTree f (Branch aroot a1 a2) (Branch broot b1 b2) = Branch (f aroot broot) (zipTree f a1 b1) (zipTree f a2 b2)
```

Let's separate out the case matches:

```
zipTree :: (a -> a -> b) -> Tree a -> Tree a -> Tree b
zipTree f Leaf _ = Leaf
zipTree f (Branch aroot a1 a2) t2 =
  case t2 of
    Leaf -> Leaf
    Branch broot b1 b2 -> Branch (f aroot broot) (zipTree f a1 b1) (zipTree f a2 b2)
```

For clarity, let's express `zipTree` as a function of two arguments, using lambdas:

```
zipTree :: (a -> a -> b) -> Tree a -> (Tree a -> Tree b)
zipTree f Leaf = \ _ -> Leaf
zipTree f (Branch aroot a1 a2) = \ t2 ->
  case t2 of
    Leaf -> Leaf
    Branch broot b1 b2 -> Branch (f aroot broot) ((zipTree f a1) b1) ((zipTree f a2) b2)
```

Does that help point the way to implementing it using `foldTree`? I've parenthesized things suggestively.

---

In a comment, you wrote

```
zipTree :: (a -> a -> b) -> Tree a -> Tree a -> Tree b
zipTree f atree btree = g btree
 where
   g = foldTree (const Leaf) callback atree
   callback aroot fWithA1 fWithA2 b =
     case b of
       Leaf -> Leaf
       (Branch broot b1 b2) -> Branch (f aroot broot) (fWithA1 b1) (fWithA2 b2)
```

Let's see if we can make this any more readable.

First, we can inline `g` at its call site:

```
zipTree f atree btree = foldTree (const Leaf) callback atree btree
```

Next, we can drop the explicit abstraction and application of `atree` and `btree`:

```
zipTree f = foldTree (const Leaf) callback
```

The next step is purely a matter of convention: main worker functions like your `callback` tend to be named `go` in Haskell code. In the context of a fold, I sometimes call the "we're done" function (here `const Leaf`) `stop` in contrast. Let's pause to put these all in place:

```
zipTree :: (a -> a -> b) -> Tree a -> Tree a -> Tree b
zipTree f = foldTree (const Leaf) go
  where
    go aroot fWithA1 fWithA2 b =
      case b of
        Leaf -> Leaf
        (Branch broot b1 b2) -> Branch (f aroot broot) (fWithA1 b1) (fWithA2 b2)
```

The last bit here is also a matter of taste. You don't use any of the other arguments of `go` when `b` is a leaf, so I think it's a bit easier to follow if you define the function in multiple lines (whatever you call them) rather than using a `case` expression.

```
zipTree :: (a -> a -> b) -> Tree a -> Tree a -> Tree b
zipTree f = foldTree (const Leaf) go
  where
    go _ _ _ Leaf = Leaf
    go aroot fWithA1 fWithA2 (Branch broot b1 b2) =
      Branch (f aroot broot) (fWithA1 b1) (fWithA2 b2)
```

This is no more correct and no more efficient than your version. I think it's a little easier to look at, but you should use whichever *you* find most understandable.

---

I just noticed that your definition has a more specific type than it needs to. This makes it less useful and also makes the compiler less able to detect mistakes in its implementation. Specifically, you require the two argument trees to have elements of the same type. Let's generalize:

```
zipTree :: (a -> b -> c) -> Tree a -> Tree b -> Tree c
zipTree f = foldTree (const Leaf) go
  where
    go _ _ _ Leaf = Leaf
    go aroot fWithA1 fWithA2 (Branch broot b1 b2) =
      Branch (f aroot broot) (fWithA1 b1) (fWithA2 b2)
```

I would personally go one step further in readability, using scoped type variables to give `go` a type signature.

```
-- This line goes at the very top of the file.
{-# language ScopedTypeVariables #-}

zipTree :: forall a b c. (a -> b -> c) -> Tree a -> Tree b -> Tree c
zipTree f = foldTree (const Leaf) go
  where
    go :: a -> (Tree b -> Tree c) -> (Tree b -> Tree c) -> Tree b -> Tree c
    go _ _ _ Leaf = Leaf
    go aroot fWithA1 fWithA2 (Branch broot b1 b2) =
      Branch (f aroot broot) (fWithA1 b1) (fWithA2 b2)
```

Comment: With a little help from my senior colleague, I managed to implement the following

```
zipTree :: (a -> a -> b) -> Tree a -> Tree a -> Tree b
zipTree f atree btree = g btree
  where 
    g = foldTree (const Leaf) callback atree
    callback aroot fWithA1 fWithA2 b = case b of
      Leaf -> Leaf
      (Branch broot b1 b2) -> Branch (f aroot broot) (fWithA1 b1) (fWithA2 b2)
```
Huge thanks to the step-by-step guide!!!!
Any improvement suggestion on the above?

Comment: I pieced together what you wrote (block formatting doesn't work in comments) and extended my answer to comment on it.

Comment: How does the fWithA1 and fWithA2 work? Do those functions not need to be defined? Sorry a little confused on the implementation.

Comment: @pranp2001, those are parameters of `go`.